# Why does linprog only give one value of x1 or x2 and not a combination of both?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

Hi I have the following code using linprog

```
for K = 1:3;
   for M = 1:3; 

      PV_output(:,:,K) = real(PV_power_output(:,:,K));
      PV =reshape(PV_output(:,:,1),8760,1); 
      WT_output(:,:,M) =  WT_power_output(:,:,M);
      WT = reshape(WT_output(:,:,1),8760,1);
    PVenergy = sum(sum(PV_output(:,:,1)));
   WTenergy = sum(sum(WT_power_output(:,:,1)));
   % Linprog
   f = [((CRF*CC_PV)/PVenergy)+OM_PV; ((CRF*CC_WT)/WTenergy)+OM_WT];
   A(:,:) = [-PV  -WT];
   b(:,:)  = -0.25.*Demand(:);
   lb = zeros(2,1);
 ub = [max_PV_area/PV_area; max_WT_area/WT_area]';
   [x(:,K,M), fval, exitflag] = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,ub)
    end
end
```

Where PV = 8760x2 , WT = 8760 x 2 and x = 2x1. When I run this program the optimisation converges with an exit flag of 1 but I either get a value of x1 =0 and a value of x2 equal to a certain integer.

Why doesn't the output give a mixture of the results (i.e a non-zero value of both x1 and x2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a linear programming solver will return a solution at a vertex of the polytope defined by the constraints. An optimal solution will always lie at such a vertex.

Comment: so in other words you are saying that a linear program can only have a non zero value of one of its x's?? which is what my problem is here

Comment: No. I did not say that. But apparently, linprog has found a solution. That solution will usually lie at a vertex, and since the lower bounds of your variables are at 0, the solution is exactly that - at a vertex.

Comment: I have tried changing the lb to lb = ones(2,1) - in this case there is a non zero x1 and x2 but the optimisation does no converge (exit flag = -2)

Comment: +1 and just a little more: in the degenerate case you may have infinitely many solutions between vertices but even in that case the vertices are optimal. (I am sure woodchips knows it, perhaps he did not want to mention it.)

Comment: Yes, I was being lazy in my response. I assume the active-set solver should always find a vertex even in the degenerate case, but this need not be true for the interior point solver.